# Gravity form hook that fires on user activation by email

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have Gravity Forms Registration Add On installed.
I need to update a usermeta value right after the user activates his account which is being done via email with an activation key.

I also need access to the entry/lead for which the activation is occurring for as that is where I will get the value from to update the user metavalue.
E.g of what I am trying to do.

```
add_action( 'gform_user_registered','myfunction');

function myfunction(user_id,entry){
   update_user_meta(user_id, 'somekey',entry[2]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_function($user_id, $feed, $entry, $user_pass){

 update_user_meta($user_id, 'somekey','some_value');
}
add_action( 'gform_user_registered', 'my_function', 10, 4 );
```

do a var_dump of $entry to see what the fields contain.